# Silverlight Hosted in Winforms

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, winforms, silverlight

I would like to host a silverlight control in winforms via a winforms browser, but for it to work I need some way for the forms to talk to the silverlight, and also the other way around.  Would it be possible to somehow have the two interact with each other using JavaScript as a middleman?  I.e., have the form speak to the browser's javascript, and have that speak to the silverlight control?  Is there a better way?  Or even a way at all?    (other than compiling the code as silverlight and wpf)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think using the Windows Forms WebBrowser control is your best bet.  To do this, you'll need your Silverlight app on a webpage, then you point your WebBrowser at the page's URI.

To keep your WebBrowser control from acting like IE, I'd recommend setting the following:

```
webBrowser.AllowNavigation = false;
webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
webBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
webBrowser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

Calling methods on your form from within Silverlight is easy enough to do.  To start, you need a class that has all the methods you want to call from Silverlight.  You can use your form itself or another object, but you need to mark the class with the [ComVisible(true)] attribute.  Then you assign your object to the WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting property.  This exposes your object as "window.external" on the webpage.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ......
    webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;
    ......
    public void CallMeInForm(string something)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Silverlight said: " + something);
    }
}
```

That's it for inside your Windows Forms project.  Inside of your Silverlight app, you need to pick up this ObjectForScripting and invoke methods on it.  To call the method in my example above, use the following lines:

```
using System.Windows.Browser;
......
ScriptObject myForm = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("external");
myForm.Invoke("CallMeInForm", "testing 1 2 3");
```

The Invoke command lets you pass any number and type of parameters to your function, although I suspect it wouldn't like it very much if you try passing complex datatypes around.  But if you needed to do so, you could always use serialization.

Calling Silverlight functions from your form seems to be the tricker direction.  I haven't figured this one out completely yet.

In your Silverlight app, you also expose functions to the webpage.  To do this, use the HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject() function.  Again, you can pass in any class with methods you want to expose.  For a method to be exposed, though, you have to mark it with the [ScriptableMember] attribute.

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
......
[ScriptableMember]
public void CallMeInSilverlight(string message)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Alert("The form said: " + message);
}
```

At this point, your method is exposed to JavaScript on the page and you could call it like so, assuming you added `id="silverlightControl"` to your `<object>` element:

```
document.getElementById('silverlightControl').Content.Page.CallMeInSilverlight("testing 1 2 3");
```

Notice the `Page` property?  That's what the call to `RegisterScriptableObject()` gave us.  Now, let's wrap this into a tidy JavaScript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallMe(message) {
        var control = document.getElementById('silverlightControl');
        control.Content.Page.CallMeInSilverlight(message);
    }
</script>
```

And now we can call the `CallMe()` method from the Windows Forms app like so:

```
public void CallToSilverlight()
{
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("CallMe", new object[] { "testing 1 2 3" });
}
```

Comment: That's awesome!  I hope you can figure out how to get it to work from WebBrowser to WinForm.  I haven't seen anyone else on the web do this (or even try...) so it would be great if you can figure it out.

Comment: have you ever figured out how to call Silverlight from the host Form?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Desklighter](http://www.blendables.com/labs/Desklighter/Default.aspx). Not exactly what you are looking for but it does proof that it should be possible?

Answer (score 1):

If all you *really* need to do is host Silverlight in a desktop app, I'd suggest you check out [Jeremiah Morrill](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/)'s [SilverlightViewport](http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/) project. It allows you to embed a Silverlight application in a WPF or XNA app. It's still very alpha, but you might find it useful.

Here's a picture to wet your appetite:

http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=silverlightviewport&DownloadId=97946

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight in a winform app just sounds like bad news. It would mean you are running to different CLR's in a single app and would have to deal with alot of added complexity to make it work. If possible consider using the full WPF within your app instead here is a [link](http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2008/06/24/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms/) showing you how.

Comment: The CoreCLR used by Silverlight supports this scenario of running in process with other CLRs, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing. I was trying to stress that although you can do it, it might not be advisable to do so. Still a neat way to bend the technology to your will.

Comment: Umm...  The CoreCLR will be running on the client.  It doesn't run on the server does it?

Comment: Sometimes various technologies have to interact. This is why MSFT create the ability to do so. In an Ideal world all apps would be single function apps. Many of my clients are businesses and once you start seeing the requirements there is almost no other choice. Unless of course there are better technologies an then still its left up to the programmer to know how to implement them.