# Hosting Silverlight App in VB.Net WinForm application

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight app and winform app. My requirement changed to Display the Silverlight app inside th WinForm app developed in VB.Net on a form. Is there workaround for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198360/silverlight-hosted-in-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what you need:
[Silverlight Hosted in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198360/silverlight-hosted-in-winforms)