# Silverlight app hosted in browser control prompting

Tags: winforms, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that I can run from Internet Explorer 8.
When I attempt to host it in a Winforms browser control as described here: [Silverlight Hosted in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198360/silverlight-hosted-in-winforms) it display a web page that says "To view this content, please install" and has a "Click now to install" button.
Unfortunately, SL4 is already installed.  However I did try to follow the instructions.  But was prompted, of course, that SL4 was already installed on my system.
I seems that at one spot IE/Silverlight cannot see that Silverlight runtime is installed, but at anoter spot it can see it.  This has become a significant roadblock.
The client OS is Win 7 64-bit.  I have no idea if other versions of OS are exhibiting the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Silverlight (the plugin) is 32-bit only. You can not run it from a 64-bit application.**

If you can [easily] force the application to run in a 32-bit context, then you're in luck -- change the "target" of the VS project from "Machine Independent" to "x86".

The above situation describes exactly what I ran into when trying to run SL (32-bit) in a Windows Sidebar Gadget (default 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit); this is somewhat interesting, it implies that all (or at least almost all of) the components behind IE are 64-bit ready. The "holdup" and why IE normally only runs in 32-bit is that it's a chick-and-egg problem with all the plugins, BHOs, and ActiveX components used. However, the (IE) Browser Host will happily run as 64-bit.

Comment: That appears to be the asnwer.  It is working fine on 32 bit machine(had to go find one).  Thank you.  Although aware of the setting for targeting specific CPUs, in all the time I have been building .NET apps I have never even considered changing it.