# Is it possible to show SilverLight busy indicator inside Winforms application?

Tags: c#, .net, busyindicator

Currently i am using a simple `PictureBox` with `GIF file` inside and wonder if this is possible and if it does what the differences between this 2 options

This is what i have at this moment using `PictureBox`:

```
pictureBox1.BringToFront();
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Embedding Silverlight (or WPF more specifically) into WinForms just to show busy indicator is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [hosting SilverLight inside Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198360/silverlight-hosted-in-winforms).

While SilverLight is intended to be used in a web browser, WPF is more *native* to desktop, and WPF does have a simimar [BusyIndicator](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator), it is downloadable from [CodePlex-Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/117416).

First define a WPF user control `MyBusyIndicator`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stackoverflow.MyBusyIndicator"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then you can host this user control in Winform using an `ElementHost`, first you add the `ElementHost` from Form's designer, and in Form's constructor

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.elementHost1.Child = new Stackoverflow.MyBusyIndicator();
    }
}
```

**The differences:**

While `BusyIndicator` comes with some properties to let you customize the indicator, it adds a dependency on SL or WPF. With `PictureBox` all you need to do is preparing animated GIFs. There are many tools for generating animated GIFs.

Comment: Can i define WPF user control inside my Winforms application ?

Comment: Sure, you can. Just add a new Item->choose WPF user control

Comment: OK i added everything, now how can i see my busy indicator ?

Comment: F5 to start debugging, and you should see the busy indicator. Are there compile errors?

Comment: did you add the `elementHost1` in designer? can you see it in designer?

Comment: OK i forget to add <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" /> but BusyIndicator is not recognize in my solution, where can i see my controller name ?

Comment: in the XAML code there is also this line `xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"`, don't forget it, and you need to reference the downloaded `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll` first.

Comment: the dll added as reference, where i need to put this line ? (see my update)

Comment: compare my code with yours, you can find the difference

Comment: BTW i added Name="_busyIndicator" to try to stop it from code and the compiler cannot find it

Comment: that is because you can't access it from winform... that is another question, though. My answer just show it is possible to show sl/wpf control in winform, but my suggestion is using PictureBox to show animated gif, that is much easier.

Comment: i am using PictureBox and only want to show how to do that with other way. so how can i stop it from code ?

Comment: Define a `StopBusyIndicator()` method in your user control, inside that method, set BusyIndicator's IsBusy="False" (you need to give the BusyIndicator a name, of course). And from WinForm, you can call `myUserControl1.StopBusyIndicator()`.

Comment: @kennyzx can you please update your example to add start / stop functionality in your code.