# How to start my BusyIndicator from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, busyindicator

I have this User control: I added this user control to my Winforms application (simple BusyIndicator):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UserControl1"             
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



   public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetIndicator(bool isBusy)
        {
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = isBusy;
        }
    }
```

Now from my main form i try to start my `BusyIndocator`:

```
UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
uc.SetIndicator(true);
```

Also if i am changing `IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"` into `IsBusy="true` i can see my BusyIndicator but then i cannot stop it.

But nothing happening, what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: 1)this is winforms or wpf? It should be latter, but why winforms tag?. 2)You bind to `IsBusy` to `IsBusy` in the datacontext, then why do you manually set `IsBusy` property in `SetIndicator` method? 3)Where do you set the datacontext ?

Comment: 1) this is winforms 2) i set busyIndicator.IsBusy = isBusy; in SetIndicator function 3) what do you mean datacontext ?

Comment: Since when does winforms use xaml?

Comment: I added wpf usercontrol after ask and other show me that its possible

Comment: 1)This can't be winforms, are you sure? Are you using winforms/wpf interop? 2)Why do you set `busyIndicator.IsBusy` when you're using DataBinding ? 3) I think you have the wrong understanding of the technology you use. Please start by learning [wpf here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you show me how to fix it ? i don't need WPF but only to start and stop it

Comment: I'm afraid. It seems you're using wpf but you claim you're not using wpf and you don't need it. Please make yourself clear. This isn't winforms, this is wpf. Learn about wpf databinding. If I just fix your code it won't help you in anyway.

Comment: I am using Winforms, today i ask this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674884/is-it-possible-to-show-silverlight-busy-indicator-inside-winforms-application and answer show me how to do that, i don't using WPF so i don't want to learn it, only make this simple BusyIndictor to work

Comment: `UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
uc.SetIndicator(true);` Is this your actual code? Don't create a new UI Control and expect it to do anything, it's not connected to the host container properly (This is true regardless of which technology you are using). You should already have an instance of your UI Control in your form. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use data binding since you are not familiar with WPF, use code to set the value of `IsBusy`.

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" /> //remove IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"
```

In your Form, define an instance of `UserControl1` and give it a name `uc`;

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{        
    UserControl1 uc; //this is the "instance".
    public MyForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uc = new UserControl1();
        uc.SetIndicator(true); //start the busy indicator
        this.elementHost1.Child = uc;
    }
}
```

And if you want to stop it, call

```
uc.SetIndicator(false); //stop the busy indicator
```

Comment: @kennuzx Can you please share your ``SetIndicator()`` method. I can't figure out what to do, in the code for user control, the ``IsBusy`` property is inaccessible.